# magento: fast_backend vs slow_backend vs backend - What is going on here?

Tags: caching, magento

Heard some talk about this being something that can be set in `apt/etc/local.xml` but I didnt see any of it there by default..  Maybe you can add it?

Anyway.  It was described to me that the `fast_backend` gets some of the magento stuff while the slow_backend get the other stuff and if `fast_backend` fails, then it will failover to `slow_backend`.

Where do I set these options?
What is stored in fast_backend?
What is stored in slow_backend?

What is the option "backend" for and what is stored there?

Answer (score 2):

take a look at the local.xml.additional in the same folder hints on how to configure it properly.

also, http://www.fabrizio-branca.de/magento-caching-internals.html gives a good overview about the magento caches.